# Variable defines as variable of the System.Object type

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a variable of type **ConnectionTesterStatus**. When I compare it in the **switch** block, I'm getting an error:

*Operator '==' cannot be used with a left hand side of type 'UnityEngine.ConnectionTesterStatus' and a right hand side of type 'System.Object'.*

```
private var natCapable : ConnectionTesterStatus = ConnectionTesterStatus.Undetermined;

function TestConnection()
{
    // Start/Poll the connection test, report the results in a
    // label and react to the results accordingly    
    natCapable = Network.TestConnection();
    switch(natCapable) // Error
    {
        case ConnectionTesterStatus.Error:
            //...
            break;
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about Unityscript but the variable declaration in the first line looks odd. Try replacing it with the declaration made in the Network scripting api reference. Also check return type of TestConnection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cast natCapable to UnityEngine.ConnectionTesterStatus

like so:

```
natCapable = Network.TestConnection() as ConnectionTesterStatus;
```

Comment: In these case I'm getting an error: ';' expected. Insert a semicolon at the end

Comment: Sorry that was C#, updated to UnityScript (I hope, somebody who is fluent in UnityScript can review the cast)

Comment: Unfortunately it says that 'UnityEngine.ConnectionTesterStatus' is a value type. The 'as' operator can only be used with reference types.